# Nativescript-vue native iOS Navigation button disappears after setting title on ActionBar

Tags: ios, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

When I use just plain ActionBar:

```
<ActionBar/>
```

when I changing route with:

```
this.$navigateTo(Catalog)
```

the native ios Back button appears normally,
but when I change action-bar like this:

```
<ActionBar title="some title"/>
```

or put other elements inside action-bar like this:

```
<ActionBar>
    <NavigationButton text="Go back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" @tap="goBack" />
<ActionBar/>
```

the default native ios Back button disappearing.

What I need in the end is default ios action-bar with custom title and native ios back button that appears when I navigate between components. Please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem. I was using ActionBar in my main component(where tabs where defined). Instead, I removed it from my main component and added its own ActionBar for every component. That solved the problem. Now the default ios back-button displaying properly with any other combinations of params or nested elements and it doesn't matter wether you route to frame of same component or not.

Comment: Had the same issue, If you're using Frames, use one ActionBar within each Frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my end, the `NavigationButton` is still visible when I use the exact code snippet above, tested with iOS v12.1.4. Please share the Playground sample if you still have the issue on your end.

However, you will not be able to modify the tap handler on iOS as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#ios-specifics).

> In iOS, the back button is used explicitly for navigation. It
>   navigates to the previous page and you cannot handle the tap event to
>   override this behavior.
>
> If you want to place a button on the left side of the ActionBar and
>   handle the tap event (e.g., show slide-out), you can use ActionItem
>   with ios.position="left".

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, here: 
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=ig4tRt&v=2
I reproduced the app on playground, please have a look at Catalog tab (2nd tab) and try to tap any category to go to subcatalog component, the title is appearing and the back button - is not.

Comment: I don't see NavigationButton code snippet anywhere in your sample.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=ig4tRt&v=4
Added NavigationButton, but it does nothing as I stated before, the ios itself at default adds back button. For example if you remove title and leave only ActionBar without nested elements it will itself add nav button and it will work.

Comment: According to your app design, I don't think you even need a frame at root level as you use tab navigation. There is no actual need for NavigationButton either as all your frames are having only one page at history. There is nothing to go back to when you hit back button.

Comment: Well, the point is - I need routing inside each tab. I'm not sure if my choice of app design is good, but as far as I can see the back-button appears just normally if I don't add additional elements to action-bar, and it appears when I go to different component, ie from Catalog->Subcatalog - and when I press back-button it goes back to Catalog just as I need. The problem is - I want to add title to action-bar, and then it breaks back-button appearance... Could you maybe point me at example of internet shop app with tab-like routing?

Comment: I could say your design is fine but you don't need a back button there, it's meaning less until you navigate to a different view. All your frames are still holding root page, no detail page is there yet.